# Crm Dynamics Plugin to call a contact

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am new to dynamics crm programming. Therefore I am having difficulties in understanding few basic things. I am trying to write a plug-in that would call a selected contact when a custom menu button is clicked. All I can understand is I have to create a menu button on the ribbon and handle its events however I cannot find how to create a menu button programmatically. I should be able to do this because when our software is installed and configured for a crm server the UI of the crm pages needs to be updated automatically. The flow is like this. Go to contacts, select a contact and when you click the custom menu button (should be available on the ribbon after our product's installation) the option to call home, office or mobile should be presented to the user and then the call should be placed to the contact. How can I achieve this? Is it handling the javascript events or are there any readily available API to handle the ribbon menu items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ribbon is defined in the Ribbon XML of the solution.  You can't programmatically create a button on the fly (although you can use javascript to hide/disable it).  Try the [Ribbon Editor](http://erikpool.blogspot.com/2011/10/new-crm-2011-ribbon-editing-tool.html) to get your feet wet with the ribbon.

From there you can use javascript on the click of the button to perform whatever functions you need.